# Issue with collapsing toolbar in marshmallow and above

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am facing a little issue with Collapsing toolbar and only for the devices having OS marshmallow and above, for lower versions its working fine

following is my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fp_dashboard_backgrd"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <include
                layout="@layout/filter_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/fund_screener_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ActionBar">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text=" Fund Screener "
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_txt_20" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/scrolll"
        layout="@layout/recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/imageViewProgress"
        layout="@layout/layout_bull_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here are the first image showing when i scroll up

[image]

and when i scroll down i get this extra white space above my `toolbar` I am not sure what is going wrong. check below image. As you guys can see white space above my Fund Screener toolbar

[image]

Guys please help me I have done lot of changes and research but not able to get any solution. Please help

**EDIT**

filter_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spnAMCName"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/SpinnerBottomLine" />

    <com.app.widgets.TextViewRobotoRegular
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_asset_type"
        android:textColor="@color/fp_light_gray"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <com.app.widgets.TextViewRobotoLight
            android:id="@+id/btnequity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_border_default"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:text="@string/equity"
            android:textColor="@color/fp_light_gray"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <com.app.widgets.TextViewRobotoLight
            android:id="@+id/btndebt"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_border_default"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:text="@string/debt"
            android:textColor="@color/fp_light_gray"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <com.app.widgets.TextViewRobotoLight
            android:id="@+id/btnhybrid"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_border_default"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:text="@string/hybrid"
            android:textColor="@color/fp_light_gray"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spnFundSubCategory"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerBottomLine" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spnFundNature"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerBottomLine" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try adding `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"`...to the toolbar

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 i had used exitUntilCollapsed but the issue happen with it is when i scroll down my view does not comes immediately I have to scroll two times on my recycler view to see the view that is hidden

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"` to toolbar? Just saying, if it can help to force toolbar stay on top when scrolling down.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` where you are including your `layout="@layout/filter_search"`. This is causing `actionBarSize` space above your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in expanded mode. Just remove it as follows.

```
     <include
            layout="@layout/filter_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

I hope this works for you.Thank You

Comment: not working bro view is getting hidden behind toolbar

Comment: @eLemEnt I run demo in my system. After removing `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from `<include ../>` its works fine for me. So try to rebulid the project. I up-voted your question for more support.

Comment: which os you run the demo ?

Comment: bro no its not working I will upvote your answer for your effort but sorry will not accept it :(

Comment: @eLemEnt try to remove `android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"` also because including layouts height and width already mentioned in its corresponding layout

Comment: Bro ur right but since i am giving margin_top for the include layout i need to give width and height otherwise it gives error for margin_top